# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0

Tags: android, firebase

I get the following  error while upgrading a firebase project from old domain to new google firebase domain.

> Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0

I followed the steps mentioned on the [Firebase documentation](http://firebase.google.com), in the section [Add Firebase to your Android Project, topic Available libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries).

What are my options to resolve this error?

Comment: Adding Firebase is now Very easy refer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41564507/5996106

Answer (score 562, accepted):

## Update Aug 2017

As of version `11.2.0` Firebase and Google Play services dependencies are available via [Google's Maven Repo](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven).  You no longer need to use the Android SDK manager to import these dependencies.

In your root `build.gradle` file add the repo:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    // ...
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
  }
}
```

If you are using gradle `4.0` or higher you can replace `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` with just `google()`.

---

The `9.0.0` version of Firebase was built using Google Play services 9.0 and is now available under the new packaging `com.google.firebase:*`

See Release Notes for Google Play services 9.0
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#may_2016_-_v90

New versions of packages **Google Play Services** (rev 30) and **Google Repository** (rev 26) were just released in the SDK manager so it's likely you just need to update.

---

## Downloading Google Play Services and Google Repository

#### From Android Studio:

1. Click `Tools` > `Android` > `SDK Manager`.
2. Click into the `SDK Tools` tab.
3. Select and install `Google Play Services` (rev 30) and `Google Repository` (rev 26).  See the image below.
4. `Sync` and `Build` your project.

[image]

---

#### From IntelliJ IDEA:

As of April 2017, the latest versions of Google Play Services and Repository are listed below.

1. Click `Tools` > `Android` > `SDK Manager`.
2. Under the `Packages` panel, Look for the `Extras`.
3. Select and install `Google Play Services` (rev 39) and `Google Repository` (rev 46). See the image below.
4. `Perform a gradle project sync` and `Build` your project.

[image: Updated image of the SDK Manager as of April 2017]

Comment: Just doing the update as described worked for rev 38 to 39 and "Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0"

Comment: Worked for me to solve 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1' as well!

Comment: Now its rev 38 and 41 and it still does solve the problem.

Comment: Everything is updated in SDK Tools but now my emulators have not updated google play services version, can anyone tell me how can I update my emulators with updated play services.

Comment: I already had Google Play Services on mine but I had to force an update and it worked just fine :) thanks

Answer (score 22):

Go to Android SDK Manager and install the latest version of below two libraries

1. Google Play Services
2. Google Repository

Answer (score 13):

`Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1`

If you ever get this error and you are using Android studio 2.2 that comes with firebase component integrated in it which has libraries version 9.6.0 by default and you are adding the latest dependencies like 9.6.1  . You might need to downgrade `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1` to `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.0`

Or check the ***library version*** of your pre-installed firebase and ***make sure it is of the same version*** with the new library you are trying to add or added to your project.

Answer (score 4):

Tried all the above, use the **Firebase Assistant**! It is the simplest way to solve this. First remove all the dependencies you added to the build.gradle (using the manual method) and then in Android Studio:

```
Click Tools > Firebase to open the Assistant window.
```

It really is as easy as that.

Comment: Where is the Firebase Assistant in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 3):

Faced myself and seen several times in comments for similar questions - that even after installing "latest" **Google Play Services** and **Google Repository** still having the same issue.

The thing is that they may be latest for your current revision of **Android SDK Tools**, but not that latest your app build requires.

In such case make sure to install latest version of **Android SDK Tools** first, and probably **Android SDK Platform-tools** (both under **Tools** branch). Also please note you may need to go through this several times if you haven't updated for a long time (i.e. install latest **Android SDK Tools** and **Android SDK Platform-tools**, then restart Android SDK Manager, then repeat), since the updates seem to be going through some critical mandatory milestones and you cannot install the very latest if you currently have the revision which is pretty "old".

[image: Android SDK Manager - Tools and Platform-tools]

Answer (score 3):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {


        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following are the prerequisites if you want to add firebase to your project.

1. For working with Firebase you should install Android Studio 1.5 or higher.
2. Download the latest Google Play services SDK from through Android SDK Manager.
3. The device should be running Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) or newer, and Google Play services 9.2.0 or newer.

I could only find out all this after hours of struggle.

Source: [Adding Firebase to your Android App](http://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/material-design/firebase-android-tutorial-getting-started/)

Comment: Unfortunately link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

If using command line tools, do

```
sdkmanager 'extras;google;m2repository'
sdkmanager 'extras;android;m2repository'
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to Update

Android SDK : SDK Tools -> Support Repository -> Google Repository

After updating the Android SDK need to sync gradle build in Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on top of adding google() in repositories for the project level gradle file, I had to also include it in the app level gradle file.

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the above methods are not working then change `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'` to `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0'` in your app level build.gradle file.
This would surely work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions and nothing worked for me. Changing gradle version worked for me.

I changed following inside `gradle-wrapper.properties`

from

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update October 2022

`com.google.firebase-core` has been deprecated in October 2022. Instead of `firebase-core`, use `firebase-analytics` or `firebase-analytics-ktx`.

> The firebase-core library is deprecated and no further versions will
> be released. This SDK included the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics.
>
> Now, to use Google Analytics or a product that recommends adding
> Google Analytics, you need to explicitly declare the Analytics
> dependency: com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics or
> com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx.

[Release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2022-10-12)