# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

As per [Firebase codelab Android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#5) tutorial,while adding `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0` in build.gradle dependencies, getting below error:

> Error:(28, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0

See below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This one shouldn't be marked as duplicate because this one actually gives a direct answer while the other is vague. The other one doesn't specify what needs to be added like the answer below.

Comment: Adding Firebase is now Very easy refer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41564507/5996106

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 9.0.0 version of Firebase was built using Google Play services 9.0

While adding `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'` into my build.gradle, gradle sync successfully.

I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310188/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core9-0-0).