# Android studio not resolving firebase authentication dependency

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My android studio is unable to sync my project. I get this error:

> Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1

What should I do?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382907/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-auth9-0-0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310188/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core9-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

Switch this to: `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2`

Answer (score 0):

Update your Google repositories in the Android SDK. That solved it for me