# Unable to add FCM : failed to resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2, though I have updated my google play services

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-cloud-messaging

when I am trying to add `compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2"`
in my build.gradle(app) 
it was showing following error

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2
<a href="openFile:/home/admin/Downloads/ZaakItPartner/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Note: I have updated my google play services.

Comment: do you have `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`?

Comment: try this answer.............http://stackoverflow.com/a/37310513/3678308

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310188/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core9-0-0)

Comment: I have added classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'  hrskrs, waqar-younis pls see note

Comment: maybe adding your dependencies to the question would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally  I got

**need to update :** Google Play Services (rev 30) and Google Repository (rev 26)

**build.gradle(app):**

```
 dependencies { compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2"}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**build.gradle(project):**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Comment: 1) Update Google Play Services; 2) Google Repository; 3) Add dependencies { compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2"}. That´s it. No need to add the classpath, apply plugin... I´m using AS 2.1.2.