# How to fix "Failed to resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.0"?

Tags: android-studio, firebase, admob, android-gradle-plugin

I have tried to integrate *Admob Ads*. The very first step is to add these statements to `build.gradle`.

Project Level

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
```

Module level:

```
dependencies {
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.0'
        }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But when synced getting

```
 Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.0
```

How can I integrate these advertisements?

Comment: Follow this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310188/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core9-0-0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310188/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core9-0-0) but enable Google Repo 29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a  typo with the version.

---

Replace `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.0'` with `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'`

---

**Update:** 9.2.0 *is* a valid version. You might be able to use 9.2.0, but you have to update Google Services from the SDK Manager. If that doesn't work, then stick with 9.0.2 until we find something.

Comment: Version 9.2.0 was just released yesterday.

Comment: Weird... But firebase still tells us to use 9.0.2 in the quickstart, so maybe stick to 9.0.2 until it has official updates.

Comment: I just checked the docs and they say 9.2.0: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk

Comment: Not typo. I have copied this version from Google setup instructions. But it is not working. Changed it to 9.0.2 and it worked.

Comment: This is not a typo mistake, you have to update to the last version of the Google Play Services. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38139399/1143172

Comment: @icastell indeed, it isn't a typo, but it solved his error. If he wants to update, he needs to create a separate question claiming he can't update his FB version.

Comment: @AbAppletic I see your point. Yours is a possible solution but I think is better to integrate the last version, indeed the question is about 9.2.0 version not 9.0.2 and the problem is that the partner doesn't have the last version of Google Play Service.

Comment: yes this is mentioned in official google setup  documentation

Answer (score 11):

You have to update your Google Play Service to the last version, currently is 31, also your Google Repository must be the last too, now is 29.

Comment: So, you can use 9.2.0 don't you?

Comment: I didn't. I have used 9.0.2 :)

Comment: But the last version is 9.2.0 XD This is your question about.

Comment: Yes. It is not working. I switched to 9.0.2 for the time being. Might be some issue with FireBase.

Answer (score 2):

I just integrated Firebase analytics as well. I had the same problem though! What seems to fix the problem is changing `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'` to `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'`. Basically the `9.2.0` should be `9.0.2`. I was using [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk) tutorial, and it said to use `9.2.0`. I am assuming either the tutorial has a typo or something needs to be updated. This will work though! :)

Comment: Yeah, I had the same issue. And I used 9.0.2, seems like 9.2.0 is a typo.

Comment: Exact same issue fixed changing 11.2.0 to 11.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Updating google services in SDK Manager helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Update all your google services version from 9.0.2 to 9.2.0.