# Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0?

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

In my app, I am trying to use gcm services, but I cannot even get gradle to compile. I keep getting the message that I am missing 'firebase core' though I have no idea how to install this.

This is my top-level gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.0"
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
  }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }

    maven {
        url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/"
    }
}
}
```

And here is my module-level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {

compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "roof.android"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 11
    versionName "0.0.4"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTIC E.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/pom.xml'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

// "The Android Support Library package contains several libraries that can be included in your application" -- https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'

// "Native android recycler view library" -- https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'

// "A powerful image downloading and caching library for Android" -- http://square.github.io/picasso/
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

// "Volley is an HTTP library that makes networking for Android apps easier and most importantly, faster" -- https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

// "JsonWebTokens in Auth0"  -- https://auth0.com/docs/jwt
compile 'com.auth0:java-jwt:2.1.0'

// "Joda-Time provides a quality replacement for the Java date and time classes" -- http://www.joda.org/joda-time/
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.1'

// "Android loading or progress dialog widget library, provide efficient way to implement iOS like loading dialog and progress wheel" -- https://github.com/Cloudist/ACProgressLite
compile 'cc.cloudist.acplibrary:library:1.2.1'

// "A RecyclerView that is powered by Realm and lots more" -- https://github.com/thorbenprimke/realm-recyclerview
compile 'com.github.thorbenprimke:realm-recyclerview:0.9.22'

// "A beautiful ripple animation for your app" -- https://github.com/skyfishjy/android-ripple-background
compile 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'

// "A logger with a small, extensible API which provides utility on top of Android's normal Log class." -- http://jakewharton.github.io/timber/
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.2'

// "Field and method binding for Android views" -- http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'

// "An HTTP+HTTP/2 client for Android and Java applications." -- http://square.github.io/okhttp/
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'

// "Android client for Sentry"
compile 'com.joshdholtz.sentry:sentry-android:1.4.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'

}
```

Comment: This may not solve you immediate problem, but you need to move `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to the **bottom** of your module gradle file.  [Detail here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin).

Comment: @Teddy Wilson: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 14):

1. In your module Gradle file (usually the `app/build.gradle`), add the apply plugin(`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`) line at the bottom of the file to enable the Gradle plugin.
2. You should also add the dependencies for the Firebase `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging` SDK's:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
     // ...
   }

   dependencies {
     // ...
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
   }

   // ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   ```

Make sure you have the latest version of **'Google Play services'** and **'Google Repository'** installed while using **Firebase**.

Please follow below steps to install:

1. Open Android studio
2. Go to the Menu bar > Tools > Android > SDK Manager
3. Click on Tab > SDK Tools
4. Check and install **'Google Play Services'** and **'Google Repository'**
5. Click on Apply and wait for the download

Finally, **Sync** and **build** your project again.

Answer (score 4):

You want to add push notifications in your app ?

use firebase instead of GCM. it is enhanced version of GCM.

You need following dependencies for firebase push notifications.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.1'
```

for further info visit http://codingaffairs.blogspot.com/2016/06/firebase-cloud-messaging-push.html

Comment: Why do you recommend firebase?

Comment: because if you read google official blogpost about firebase. they also recommends that you should upgrade your existing apps to firebase :)

Comment: infact it has more features, easy to integrate.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0` and it worked after moving the `google()` repository above `jcenter()`.

In between I used `Build -> Clean Project`.

**./build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() // <- now on top!
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // <- now on top!
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the firebase core, you can add
`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'`
under dependencies tag in your module-level gradle file.

If you still can't resolve it, maybe you need to update the SDK to get the Google Play Services rev 30 and Google Repository rev 26 first. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310188/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core9-0-0) for the detail.

Answer (score 0):

In your android/build.gradle in your repositories section, try moving *google()* ABOVE *jcenter()*.