# The type com.google.firebase.iid.zzb cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Cordova Android project, and I have added the [Google Firebase Cloud Messaging Cordova Push Plugin](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm)

I am getting the following error on the MyFirebaseMessagingService.java file.

```
The hierarchy of the type MyFirebaseMessagingService is inconsistent
```

and

```
The type com.google.firebase.iid.zzb cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

My classpath file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="Downloads/google-play-services.jar/google-play-services.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="Downloads/google-firebase-iid.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="Downloads/firebase-messaging-9.2.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="Downloads/android-support-v4.jar (2)/android-support-v4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

I have tried various combinations of removing and adding different jar files but no luck.

Has anyone else come across this error before when adding this plugin?

Thanks for any help. I can post more code or screenshots if needed.

Comment: Hint: "class path" information in the end is a list of JAR files you are using. In other words: **text**. Screenshots are the last resort; only use that when there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

*Guessing*: you are missing something like the JAR for firebase-**core**

See their [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) for further information!

The point is: sometimes your JAR files depend on other JAR files; and that error message simply tells you that you ran into such a problem. Then you have to start searching where to acquire the "missing" part.

All of this should plug nicely into the Android studio / gradle build environment; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38293727/could-not-find-com-google-firebasefirebase-core9-0-0) for details.

Comment: Being quite dumb here, but i cannot find the core jar file anywhere. You have a link?

Comment: That link I gave you tells you how to setup your build script to automatically pull it.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed some function or method of used jar file in your project .
Create a separate library project in which add all required jar which mentioned in below link :-

https://github.com/dandar3/android-google-firebase-messaging

Now add this library project into you exiting project , will solve your problem.

Note below are the jar file which you have to include in your library project :-

1)dandar3/android-google-firebase-common
2)dandar3/android-google-firebase-iid
3)dandar3/android-google-play-services-basement 
4) https://github.com/dandar3/android-google-play-services-tasks/blob/11.2.0/libs/google-play-services-tasks.jar
5) google-firebase-messaging.jar