# No cached version for "com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0" available for offline mode Android studio 1.5.1

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to use Firebase, and am using Android Studio version 1.5.1 but if I try to sync my project after adding `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` and the plugin at the bottom `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` of the App-level build.gradle .

The error still remains the same `No cached version fof "com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0" available for offline mode`

I have tried to read existing answers on Stack Overflow, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: You probably need to [disable offline mode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28712025/4815718) so that Android Studio can download the needed files.

Comment: It has worked but now it brings another error `Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0` @qbix

Comment: You probably need to open the SDK manager and download some repositories.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37310513/4815718

Comment: Thanks @qbix , it has worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this issue.
After spend 2-3 hours i find the solution. (which works for me)

**Step 1:**

[Disable offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712025/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio)

**Step 2:**

Go to gradle-wrapper-properties

Replace this line

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

with

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Remove secure  connection.