# Failed to resolve : com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-realtime-database, build.gradle

I want to work with firebase real time database with this [link.](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/10/android-working-with-firebase-realtime-database/). After 6th step, it gives

> Failed to resolve

error.

build.gradle App module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "gc.imageuploader"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle Project module:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

So how Can I solve this problem? What should I do? What do you think about this problem?

Comment: Make sure you have  the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager

Comment: How to? I am newbie.

Comment: Check how to update the Google Play Services and Google Respository  from the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310188/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core9-0-0?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest version of **'Google Play services'** and **'Google Repository'** installed while using **Firebase**.

Please follow below steps:

1. Open Android studio
2. Go to the Menu bar > Tools > Android > SDK Manager
3. Click on Tab > SDK Tools
4. Check and install **'Google Play Services'** and **'Google Repository'**
5. Click on Apply and wait for the download

Finally, **Sync** and **build** your project again.