# Error: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:9.6.1

Tags: android, gradle, firebase

This  is Gradle app code and it show error 
 cannot compile 
 so my pull my hair not getting bug.
Please anybody ping here!!

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner          "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'

    // Google

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'


    // Firebase

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'



    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.1'

    This line getting error please anybody get in touch

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:9.6.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't been able to find an explanation of the history of `appindexing`, but from looking at the [revision history](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/commits/master/app-indexing/app/build.gradle) of the quickstart project, prior to 10.0.0, the package name was different.  Try using this in your dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.6.1'
```

This answer presumes you are using the features of the pre-10.0.0 API.  The [Migration Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/migrate) explains the differences.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Firebase version `9.8.0` or below you want to use the form `com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:<VERSION>`.  If you are using version `10.0.0` or above you want to use the form `com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:<VERSION>`.  The name was changed in version `10.0.0`.

If you are getting a "cannot resolve" error when trying this, update your Google Play Services SDK following this procedure:
[Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310188/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core9-0-0/37310513#37310513)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was API error and bug also reported to google.
so just error out.