# Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am getting this error. What should I do?

```
Error:Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1.

Searched in the following locations:
        file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio1/gradle/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.0.1/firebase-auth-10.0.1.pom
        file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio1/gradle/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.0.1/firebase-auth-10.0.1.jar
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.0.1/firebase-auth-10.0.1.pom
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.0.1/firebase-auth-10.0.1.jar
    Required by:
        project :
```

Comment: post your gradle file

Comment: try to check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37310513/2909929

Comment: my gradle file dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    
}