# Failed to resolve google auth dependency

Tags: android, gradle, google-authentication

I am attempting to follow the instructions at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating
to create a Google sign in button for my application. However, when I try to use

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'
```

I get the error "Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2". I have followed the advice of similar questions and have made sure that my SDK is up to date but no luck.

The project build:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

And the app build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "theproject.theapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.20'

    compile 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks,

Ian

Comment: Try updating google play service from android sdk manager.

Comment: @ihunter2839 have look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310188/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core9-0-0

Comment: @HemantParmar there is no dependency like **`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the Latest version of **`play-services-auth`**

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
```

just change it in Your **`Gradle.Build`**  there is no dependency like `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'`

for more information read from

**[Start Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)**

Comment: I wonder where the 11.6.2 came from... thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: welocme @ihunter2839 happy to help you

Comment: Will accept the answer after the remaining 4 min delay :)

Comment: 11.6.2 is currently the latest, and android studio now warns you to use the latest version available

Answer (score 3):

In order to use compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2' you should do the following steps.

1) Inside your build.gradle (module) replace:

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'`

with:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
```

2) Inside your build.gradle (project) you should replace:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

with:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add google() to your gradle repositories list, this is where version 11.6.2 is found for now. Something like that:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

menu: **Tools**, **Android**, **Sdk Manager**

check: **Show Package Details**

Install **Android SDK plataform 27**

**Ok**. Add marven when Android Studio ask at messages **log errors** just clicking in it.

change this lines from 25 or 26 to 27

```
compileSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 27
```

now is working.

Answer (score 0):

just update com.android.support to version 25.4.0 in your app gradle