# Firebase set up- error: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle

I'm build an app that uses in Firebase system. When I started enter the code of Firebase in my app I got this error:

```
"Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Public/Documents/Jtube2/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>"
```

I looked for this error and I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310188/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core9-0-0) but I checked my SDK manager and all is fine I don't know what my problem with my code.
Here my code for build.gradle (module:app):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here my code for build.gradle (Project:myproject):

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `google()` maven inside your `allProjects` block in your **project** `build.gradle` like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}

repositories {
    ...
}

// You need to add the google maven in this block.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In My case, I added `google()` as suggested in accepted answer. I also changed `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip` to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip` in `gradle-wrapper.properties` file.