# Setting up firebase on Android studio

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to setup firebase on my android studio.I am using a 2.2.3 version.So this is my code in app.gradle file:

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.parth.carpool"
            minSdkVersion 22
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-a`enter code here`nnotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is the error that I am receiving.

```
Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1
```

This is my project.gradle file:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

To correct this error I installed google play services, google repository, SDK platform,SDK platform tools etc. after I saw some of the posts on stackoverflow. Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310188/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core9-0-0)

In your root build.gradle file add the repo:

```
maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
```

Comment: root as in the project.gradle file or the app.gradle file?

Comment: root build.gradle @parth

Answer (score 2):

First you need to upgrade android studio to the newest version:

> If you're not using Android Studio 3.1 to develop your app, you will need to upgrade in order to get the correct version checking behavior within the IDE.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html

Then you need to use the following top level gradle file:

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
  }



dependencies {
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
 }
}

allprojects {
 repositories {
          google()
         jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
  }
```

Comment: Your gonna have to upgrade eventually, to use `google()` you need android studio 3.0+, but for older versions you can use `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`. The google() repo contains the firebase libraries and other support libraries

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio provides Awesome tool called Firebase Assistant, it handles any thing you need to setup firebase in you'r project

from **Tools->Firebase**

[image]

just pick which product you want and it'll do all the work for you

Comment: Does it mean I don't have to explicitly setup firebase?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are connected to a good network

> Goto >file -> other settings -> Under build, execution, and deployment
>   -> you will see Gradle. uncheck the checkbox offline work. Then rebuild your project.

```
 buildscript {
repositories {

    // add google here
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'

}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon you how you want to setup you can try both explicit way and implicit way of setting up firebase .the easiest one is implicit one which is given in android studio