# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

Can't run app with this dependancy

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
```

when i downgrade dependancy to : 16.0.1 it's working but the version :17.2.0 gives me error as given below

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

Initializing gradle...

Resolving dependencies...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the error message?

Comment: Error message added in my question "with exit code 1"

Comment: is your app on androidX

Comment: @Ggriffo no my isn't on androidX

Comment: You have to migrate it to android X. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your top-level build.gradle to use the latest version of the google services plugin. It looks like you're using a very old one that still assumes that all the Firebase and Play dependencies must be the same version, which is no longer the case.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
```

see [Failed to resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:17.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52990071/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-crash17-0-2)

Comment: in my project google-service plugin is updated
'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'

Comment: Pls don't copy the answer. If it is a duplicate question, just mark the question as duplucate. But it is not the case.

Comment: @ Gabriele Mariotti i'm not copying just telling you the solution you give me i already tried it.

Comment: @ParthBhanderi could you post here your top-level build.gradle

Comment: @ParthBhanderi usefull link to set up firebase to your project https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup