# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:16.0.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

How to solve this error?

> Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:16.0.1

I have given my dependency screenshot here.please help me out..

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310188/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core9-0-0)

Comment: how to solve -> don't use this dependency. It's goddamn huge and you need only the smaller components

Answer (score 0):

You can check in the [google maven repo](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html)

The last `com.google.android.gms:play-services` **full-module** is **12.0.1**.

The dependency `com.google.android.gms:play-services:16.0.1` doesn't exist.
**Use only the single play-services components you need**.

Comment: Now this happend 

error: cannot access zzbgl
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

Comment: It wuold be useful to have a detail error. In anycase this is a separate problem. It has nothing to do with your question. You may wish to consider asking a separate question

Answer (score 0):

```
Add this to project build.gradle

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        }

    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    }
}
```